# python: DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype uint8, int64 were all converted to float64 by StandardScaler

Tags: python-3.x

I don't understand this message `/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py:645: DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype uint8, int64 were all converted to float64 by StandardScaler.
  return self.partial_fit(X, y)
/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:2: DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype uint8, int64 were all converted to float64 by StandardScaler.
  from ipykernel import kernelapp as app`

My code is :
`X = Feature_test
testX= preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X).transform(X)`

What does it mean??
And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Just cats the data type for the argument X

```
testX= preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X).transform(X.astype(np.float))
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have columns in your dataset of type integer. It's a warning, so you are good to go if you need to scale your features for a regression or a neural network.